# How to include top-level build file during Android library import?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm trying to import [this library](https://github.com/eo/battery-meter-view) as a library into my existing app. The reason I'm doing this as a source-code import than just including the maven dependency is to add modifications to the library from my end. Now this isn't the first time I've imported libraries this way but when I did it for this one, it threw an error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'config' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

I understand this is because it has a root level gradle file. Also, during import Android showed me multiple libraries so clearly this is a multi-module project. The issue here is that there is a top-level build file which has certain configuration parameters and then there are these module-level build files that reference the variables in the top-level one. Android Studio doesn't seem to import that [top-level build file](https://github.com/eo/battery-meter-view/blob/master/build.gradle) and therefore gives me the above error.

Ideally, I want to import the whole thing AS-IS without re-structuring so that I can make modifications and commit back easily. Is there a correct way to import multi-module projects that have their own top-level gradle build file as a library into one's project?

Comment: You don't need more than one `build.gradle` to build a module; so what's the point?

Comment: If you take a look at the library which I've shared it actually has 4 modules (sample, batterymeter, shapes, colorinput) inside it, so one top-level gradle file and 4 module-level gradle files. The issue isn't the number of modules. Even if I were to import 1 module, it still references variables from the top-level gradle file and android studio doesn't import that and hence the unknown property error and so I cannot import the library into my project as a library module.

Comment: Just copy the variables over to your `build.gradle` - or replace them with strings; `batterymeter` should be the only one module required, but eventually also the other two ...as they seem to be resource modules (any sane person would have packaged this as one module, if they should be required by that library).

Comment: I know that will work and have done exactly that and [made a PR](https://github.com/eo/battery-meter-view/pull/4) to that library as well. But it's inefficient because I'm changing my project's root build.gradle files to make a library work--that pollutes my project's build.gradle with those variables. I'm looking for a better alternative.